# Autocompletion plugin for c/c++ with specific header path?

Tags: autocompletion, filetype-c++

Is there a plugin which autocompletes C/C++ code from specific headers given in a specific path (i.e. `/path/`)?

If I include some headers from that path, I would get autocompletion from given header.

Comment: What do you mean by "specific headers" ? C++ headers are added for the code to be valid so what is the link with the completion ?

Comment: i mean, if i have my own created headers with math functions and anything else... so i would love that vim know about my functions for autocompletion... logically, i'm implementing alternative compiler with objs automatically linked... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Set [`'path'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27path%27) to include the path to your include files. In your example:

```
set path+=/path
```

---

#### Native completion from include files

Vim native completion is quite useful for C and C++ files, Vim can search for your include files and find candidate completion targets in them and the defaults in Vim are already pretty useful for Vim completion.

You can use the `CTRL-X CTRL-I` sequence to initiate [keyword completion](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#compl-keyword), completing keywords in the current and include files.

And `CTRL-X CTRL-D` to initiate [define completion](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#compl-define), completing macros and defines in the current and include files.

#### `set path`

The important option to customize for these is [`'path'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27path%27), which tells Vim where to search for include files.

By default, Vim will search the directory where the file lives (if you're editing `src/submodule/xyz.c`, then it will search under `src/submodule` first), the system include directory (`/usr/include`) and the current directory (which might typically be the root of your project.)

You might want to add paths to this setting, basically any include path you're passing the compiler through a `-I` flag should be of interest here.

#### Other relevant settings

Also relevant are [`'include'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27include%27) and [`'define'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27define%27), which hold patterns (regexps) used to detect `#include` and `#define` directives used for the aforementioned completion commands.

Also [`'includeexpr'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27includeexpr%27), which can be used to translate an include to a file name (useful for languages in which submodule paths are separated by `.` rather than `/`.)

These are already correctly set for C/C++ by default, so you typically don't need to set these unless you're working with a different language.

#### Other useful commands for include files

There are other commands that can become very useful once [`'path'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27path%27) is set correctly to find your include files.

For instance, see [include file search](https://vimhelp.org/tagsrch.txt.html#include-search) for commands such as `[i` and `[d` which will show you the first occurrence of a keyword (or a define) and *will go inside include files* whenever it sees an `#include` directive. This can be quite powerful, as a quick way to check a function prototype wherever it's declared.

The [`gf`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#gf) command can be used from an `#include` line to open that header file. The [`:find`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Afind) command can be used to open an include file (or really any file under `'path'`) by name.

Comment: it's a good solution, pretty slow for directories with thousand of includes, but i was looking for something more faster and without the need of press `Ctrl-X` and `Ctrl-I` keys and staying for pattern scanning...

Comment: i mean, isn't hard to write a real time header scanning, just add some regex stuff checks in a vector with all functions scanned in memory and voilà, but just i was looking to know if already exists one....

Comment: @nikomaster I guess the next step is using `tags` files that you can generate using `ctags` (`Ctrl-X Ctrl-]` default keybinding for completion using tags.) Personally I use the `vim-gutentags` plug-in to keep the `tags` file up to date. Next would be something like YouCompleteMe or some other code-aware completion plug-in. And, finally, the LSP ones (Language Server Protocol), where you have a daemon continuously compiling your code in background. There are some plug-ins for Vim/NeoVim that give you access to those. YMMV on whichever solution is right for you.

Comment: isn't even necessary to setup a local server language management, i found  `completor.vim`, it works pretty well, doesn't use too much resources, optionally you can setup a lsp, but it uses by default the `path` system's var... also it works asynchronous...